# Making an FPS counter for an Android app (having the .apk only)

Tags: java, android, frame-rate

I want to make an FPS counter for Android apps. While doing research I found a lot of examples for doing this when you have access to the source code of the app, since the counting is done in the main drawing loop.

The problem is I don't have the source code, I have only the .apk of the app so there is no way to modify it. My question is, how could this be done? (at least an idea to start with). And I am sure it can be done somehow, I've seen an app like this on Google Play.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the app that you have seen that does this?

Comment: It's called Game Bench. You can check it out. It doesn't even need root on the phone. So I'm really mind blown that I can't find information on how to do this.

Comment: They say that they do not need root access but a connection to the PC the first time (no idea why). On the reviews some people are having problems so maybe their implementation is a pure hack.

Comment: My idea is that they read the contents of the screen (like a screen recording program) multiple times per second and then compare the contents of the frames to understand if something changed or not.

Comment: I will try their app now.

Comment: The connection to the PC is needed to activate the app (see if you installed the PRO or the non-PRO version) as far as I understood, so it has no impact on the FPS counting part.

Comment: And the idea about the screen recording is quite interesting, I will look further into that, thank you. If you have any other ideas (or not), please add an answer below so I can mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just installed the app.

At the beginning they ask for the activation of USB debugging on the device. And this why it needs a connection to the PC.

So this is how they are able to get such kind of information.

I would advise you to look at USB debugging of Android apps and see what is possible there (such as taking multiple screenshots per second)